# Blender 2.90 - Some verts disappear or are unelectable when entering Weight Paint mode

Tags: vertices, weight-paint-mode

I'm currently running into an issue where certain verts on my model act as if I've hidden them and continually disappear when entering weight paint mode or sculpt mode. This isn't the first time I've had this problem, and after countless run-ins with the issue have yet to find a solution.

Here's what I've done up until this point.

- Duplicated an existing model I created to work on a copy.
- Used the RetopoFlow plugin to create smoother versions of parts of the hand to appear more like a fingerless glove.
- After I finished, I manually stitched the new RetopoFlow geo to the old geo by hand by merging verts that were close.
- I entered sculpt mode to smooth out a few parts but noticed I was unable to interact with some of the verts. I could manipulate everything, except them specifically, even after clearing all masks.
- Fearing the issue as I've run into this before, I entered weight painting mode and turned on Vertex Selection. Sure enough, the verts on the part I just created (hilighted in the images) were unselectable.
- I went into Edit Mode and attempted to unhide all.
- Unhiding all suddenly unhid *and* selected all the verts I was unable to manipulate, as if I'd hidden them.
- Reinterring Weight Paint mode, all faces connected to the verts in question are once again unselectable and can't be manipulated. But they're not really 'gone' either, as I can still go back into edit mode and unhide them again like before. Doing this however only repeats the process and doesn't actually fix anything.

This problem will make it so I can't weight paint the hand later, speaking from previous experience.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix this? This isn't the first time I've run into this problem. It usually happens when I merge two geometries, especially if the newly merged geo was created via a plane. Is there any way I can fix this or am I just screwed?

[image: These are the verts that have problems]

[image: The verts do not show up in weight paint mode]

Comment: I seem to remember that there was a bug with earlier versions of blender causing that issue. Try updating to a more modern Blender version - 3.3.10 is the earliest LTS version that is still supported as 2.93.17 LTS has now gone out of support.

Comment: The thing where they get selected after unhiding although they are not hidden is strange. Is there any duplicate geometry in this area? If it is just a bug because of an older version maybe updating helps as John suggests. Otherwise I guess it would be better if you uploaded the file (or at least the object in question) to https://blend-exchange.com and edit the link into your question.